# STRAPI : currentEnvironment name in admin ui

Tags: node.js, reactjs, strapi

I want to hide some menu from left navigation in production mode.

I've tried `NODE_ENV`, `process.env`, `NODE_ENV` etc. When I'm trying `NODE_ENV`, it returns production in development and production mode both. Any way to get config in admin ui? I can get environment name in controller using `proces.env` but I don't know how to send data from controller to admin ui.

I can get it in controller using `process.env.NODE_MODULE` or `strapi.config` but it's not accessible in react admin ui.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with webpack and can be done using following blog: https://medium.com/@justintulk/passing-environment-variables-into-your-code-with-webpack-cab09d8974b0

In webpack file you can fetch the env variables using the following link:
https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/

Comment: yeah, thats possible in core node and react but strapi is using react production build in development and production mode both. so NODE_ENV returns production in both development and production mode